# NSProgressIndicator doesn't update until the end of the loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, for-loop, dispatch-async, nsprogressindicator

I'm making an app that does a very large amount of calculation for multiple files, and so to keep track of everything that's going on, I added an NSProgressIndicator (values 0-100).

I also have a console in the app, so the `logConsole:` method writes to that console.

My loop looks like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

    for(int i = 0; i < _files.count; i++)
    {

        //Do calculations

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            [_progressBar setDoubleValue: ((i+1) / _files.count) * 100];
            [self logConsole:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Completed file #%d", (i+1)]];

        });

    }

});
```

When this loop runs, the messages are logged to the app's console (not NSLog, the actual GUI console I made) asynchronously, but the progress bar doesn't change until the entire for-loop completes.

So if there were 5 files it would look like this:

```
LOG: Completed file #1
Progress bar at 0
LOG: Completed file #2
Progress bar at 0
LOG: Completed file #3
Progress bar at 0
LOG: Completed file #4
Progress bar at 0
LOG: Completed file #5
Progress bar at 100
```

Why isn't the progress bar updating? It's running on the main thread.

Comment: Your logging is very silly. The key value in your code is `((i+1) / _files.count) * 100` but you not logging it to see if makes any sense.

Comment: @matt `logConsole:` presents information to the user, not to me as a developer. It's meant to be pretty, not to debug.

Comment: That changes nothing. Your question is "why isn't the progress bar updating"? The way to find out is to look at the values you are setting it to. You aren't looking.

Comment: @matt Even so, in my mind, the math was correct. It never occurred to me to check that it was integer math. I don't believe that's constructive.

Comment: You may be right, and if so, I apologize. Still, I think I'm right too. I'm suggesting that posting to Stack Overflow without bothering to do even the most rudimentary debugging on your own is not constructive.

Comment: And by the way, NSProgress would have given you a _much_ better way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are doing integer math, which will never result in a floating point value.  You will have to cast your values as a `double` for this to do what you want.

```
double progress = (((double)i) + 1.0) / ((double)_files.count);
[_progressBar setDoubleValue:progress * 100.0];
```

It's also worth mentioning that you wouldn't have to multiply by 100.0 if you set the `minValue` and `maxValue` of the progress bar appropriately (the default is 0.0 and 100.0).  You would want to put this in `viewDidLoad` most likely:

```
[_progressBar setMinValue:0.0];
[_progressBar setMaxValue:1.0];
```

Comment: I changed it to use doubles for each number, but it still doesn't update.

Comment: Haha to be tripped up by integer division after 6 years as a programmer is a humbling moment :)

Comment: Happens to everyone, I'm sure. :)

Comment: It will be sufficient to put only a single double value and result wiil be double like:
    **double progress = (i + 1.0) / _files.count;**

Comment: @IurieManea is correct, I just like to be extra sure.